# How to see BSON document?

Tags: mongodb

I started working with mongodb and aware how I can see data which is stored in database? I know about JavaScript shell (mongo.exe) but I want something which can give me the whole picture. Is it a way to open the data as a flat document? Or maybe it is possible to export the data to a file using some shell command? Thanks.

Comment: mongoexport --host localhost --db dbname --collection collectionname >a.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mongoexport`. It will dump collections into files with JSON content.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mongodump` and then use `bsondump` to dump collection files which is in bson format.

Comment: This is useful thank you.  It's also worth knowing that you can type bsondump <collection-name>.bson if you just want to generate the relevant JSON for one collection (like I did so that I could restore one object that was deleted in error).